# Can anybody please help me with a "graph coloring" skill?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I need to show that if $G$ is a $k$-critical graph, then the chromatic number $\chi(G−v)=k−1$? How can i prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the definition of $k$-critical: $\chi(G)=k$ but $\chi(G-v)<k$ for each $v$. In this case we must have $\chi(G-v)=k-1$, since otherwise you could colour $G-v$ with at most $k-2$ colours, then use a new colour for $v$ to get a colouring of $G$ with $k-1$ colours.